# passing query params string while using $routeProvider in angular

Tags: angularjs, routes, route-provider

Hi I'm using $routeProvider and i would like to pass the query params when changing any path, for example when i press on a button who changes the location.

let's say that my url is `localhost:9000/index-new.html#/signup?aaaaa=bbbbb`

and i press on a button that changes the href like login, it changes to

`localhost/index-new.html#/login` and i would like it to be change to 
`localhost:9000/index-new.html#/login?aaaaa=bbbbb`.

i would like to do that without building a service or listen to the even of $location and exc...

is there somthing build in like this maybe?

```
loginApp.config(['$routeProvider', 
        function ($routeProvider, $routeParams, $route) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/login', {
                    templateUrl: '../views/login/loginView.html?' +$routeParams,
                    controller: 'loginCtrl',
                    $routeparmas: 
                })
                .when('/signup', {
                    templateUrl: '../views/login/signupView.html?' + $routeParams,
                    controller: 'signupCtrl',
                })
        })
]);
```

Comment: First you can't concatenate an object and a string. Second why would you need to do this? Third ... to do it you need to use `templateUrl:function`

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that like charlietfl said. But there are two things that you can try:

1st:

```
$routeProvider
                .when('/login', {
                    templateUrl: '../views/login/loginView.html',
                    controller: 'loginCtrl',
                    params:{
                       aaaaaa: 'bbbbbb',
                       cccccc: 'dddddd'
                    }
                })
```

After you do this you can access the params like this:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$route', function($route){
    var params = $route.current.$$route.params;
}]);
```

2nd:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$location', function($location){
    var params = {
        aaaaaa: 'bbbbbbb',
        cccccc: 'ddddddd'
    };

    $location.path('/yourPathHere').search(params);
}]);
```

And you access them like this:

```
app.controller('YourPathCtrl', ['$routeParams', function($routeParams){
    var params = $routeParams
}]);
```

Comment: I don't know what my params are going to be so this is not relevant... but thanks for the help i solved it using Service. i found that angular $routeprovider isn't supporting this.